# How to I make ajax reques to rest api in cakephp

Tags: ajax, rest, cakephp, mobile

I have a user component in **cakephp** which has add/update/delete controllers methods which act as a REST API methods.

Now I want to call these controllers from a ajax request or http request.

This rest api will consume mobile app.

Thanks for help!

Answer (score 0):

Add this code to your page:

```
<script type="text/javascript"
    src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.3.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.7.2/jquery-ui.js">    
 </script>
 <script>           
 jQuery.ajax({
    type: 'POST', // Le type de ma requete
    url: 'ajaxresponse.php', // Send it to a php file
    data: {
    string: 'aStringHere' // send a string in this JSON variable
     }, 
     success: function(data, textStatus, jqXHR) {

    // In the variable data will be stored your response from your ajax function in the php file you  will make
    //Do whaever you want with it here
            alert(data); 
                  },
                  error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                    // If an error can happens, do something else
                  }
                });
 </script>
```

Here this should be your php file:

```
   <?php  
   // Here you check if you received a string
   if($_POST['string'] == true)
   { 
     // Do something here, like calling cakephp controllers and this should do it
      $avariable = "hello world!";
      echo "Whaever you put here will be sent back to your ajax function, like this variable $avariable";
   }
 ?>
```